# highlight the matched keywords in the thread bodies in a search with solr?

Tags: full-text-search, solr

Ive got the following code.

```
$params = array('defType' => 'dismax', 'qf' => 'threads.title posts.body tags.name', 'hl' => 'true');

$results = $solr->search($query, $offset, $limit, $params);
```

So the keywords will be highlighted. What i dont know how to do is pulling the data out from $results. How do I get a documents field values and then show the body and hightlight it like google/SO search? Im using solr client php but i find it difficult to understand how to use it. There is so few example codes.

could someone guide me a little...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something more specific?  Looks like you are asking someone to write the entire PHP app for you!

I am going to be digging into the PHP/Solr stuff in January, if this isn't updated by then I'll post back.